# jq: Add nested numbers?

Tags: json, jq, addition

In `jq`, how can I add numbers that are nested in streamed objects?

Example:

```
{"game":
    {"player1": {"score": 2}}}
{"game":
    {"player1": {"score": 4}}}
```

I can add these numbers using two `jq` calls:

```
$ cat foo.json | jq '.game.player1.score' | jq --slurp 'add'
6
```

How can it be done with one `jq` call?

Also, how to add the scores of two different players separately?

```
{"game":
    {"player1": {"score": 2},
     "player2": {"score": 20}}}
{"game": 
    {"player1": {"score": 4},
     "player2": {"score": 40}}}

$ cat foo.json | jq '???'
{"player1": 6, "player2": 60}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `reduce`, e.g:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs.game.player1.score as $score (0; . + $score)' file
```

Another one is:

```
jq -n '[inputs.game.player1.score] | add' file
```

But this is would not perform as well as the first with large inputs.

---

And here is a more generic one covering the second Q too

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs.game as $game ({};
  reduce ($game|keys_unsorted)[] as $player (.;
    .[$player] += $game[$player].score
  )
)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

First, here's a variant of @OguzIsmail's first solution to the first problem. It serves to validate the usefulness of the generic function:

```
   def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);
```

With this, and using the -n command-line option, the solution to the given problem is simply:

```
    sigma(inputs.game.player1.score)
```

### Second problem

In the same vein of genericity:

```
def sigmas(stream; f):
  reduce stream as $s (null;
      [., ($s | f)] | transpose | map(add));

sigmas(inputs | .game; [.player1.score, .player2.score])
| {player1: .[0], player2: .[1]}
```

Notice that `sigmas` as defined here can handle arbitrarily many summands.  A still more generic solution, avoiding the need to specify the summands as a list, is left as an (easy) exercise for the reader :-)

### jq.jq

Typically, generic functions can be included in a "standard jq library".  For example, if your utility functions are in ~/.jq/jq.jq, then assuming the pwd does not have a different jq.jq, you could write (for the solution to the first problem):

```
jq -n 'include "jq"; sigma(inputs.game.player1.score)' foo.json
```

### Robust inclusion of a library

To avoid difficulties associated with module paths, it sometimes makes sense to specify the path within the `include` or `import` directive, e.g.:

```
jq -n 'include "jq" {search: "~/jq"}; ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution that arises from the perspective that the stream of objects defines a table (i.e., a spreadsheet).  The solution is also efficient (no slurping) and robust (no assumptions about the ordering or presence of keys).

```
# The stream is assumed to consist of objects (or else arrays)
# in which same-named keys have compatible values under `+`.
# The resultant object (or array) has keys the values of which are
# the sum of the values of the corresponding keys of the
# input objects, which thus need not have the same keys.
def add_by_column(stream):
  def add(b): reduce (b|keys_unsorted[]) as $k
                (.; .[$k] += b[$k]);
  reduce stream as $x (null; add($x));


add_by_column(inputs | .game | map_values(.score) )
```

Notice that this assumes that the `-n` command-line option is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an solution with a helper function which uses

- [`Update assignment |=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Update-assignment:|=) to flatten `{"player1": {"score": 4}}` objects to `{"player1": 4}`
- [`to_entries[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to convert the rows to a canonical `{"key":"player1", "value": 2}` form

Once the rows are in canonical form a simple [`Reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Reduce) does the final aggregation.

```
def kvrows: inputs[] | .[] |= .[] | to_entries[] ; # {"key":"player1","value": 2}...
reduce kvrows as $e ({}; .[$e.key] += $e.value)    # compute sums
```

Sample execution assuming the above in `test.jq` and data in `test.json`

```
$ jq -Mn -f test.jq test.json
{
  "player1": 6,
  "player2": 60
}
```